# Gaussian integral with another function

Tags: integration

[integraton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCrR3.jpg)
dear friends
any one can help me to solve this Gaussian  integral

$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\exp\left(- \sum_{i=1}^n(r_i - A)^{2}\right)}{A} dA$$

Comment: What did you try? Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

By writing the integral as follows

$$\int_a^b \frac{1}{A}e^{-(r_1 - A)^2}\ e^{-(r_2 - A)^2} \ldots e^{-(r_n - A)^2}\ dA$$

we can easily turn it into

$$\int_a^b \prod_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{A}e^{-(r_k - A)^2}$$

The productory is finite, hence we can take it out from the integral, also because Gaussian integrals are absolutely convergent.

By the change of variable

$$y = r_k - A$$ we eventually get

$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n} \int_{r_k - b}^{r_k - a} \frac{1}{r_k - y} e^{-y^2}\ dy$$

The integral is not doable yet, but due to the $e^{-y^2}$ term, which goes to zero really fast, we may attempt one more approximation, using Taylor series for that term:

$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n} \int_{r_k - b}^{r_k - a} \frac{1}{r_k - y} \sum_{p = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^p}{p!} y^{2p}\ dy$$

$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n} \sum_{p = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^p}{p!} \int_{r_k - b}^{r_k - a} \frac{1}{r_k - y}  y^{2p}\ dy$$

That integral can be solve by the mean of Hypergeometric functions:

$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n} \sum_{p = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^p}{p!} \left( \frac{y^{2 p+1} \, _2F_1\left(1,2 p+1;2 p+2;\frac{y}{r_k - a}\right)}{(r_k - a) (2 p+1)} - \frac{y^{2 p+1} \, _2F_1\left(1,2 p+1;2 p+2;\frac{y}{r_k - b}\right)}{(r_k - b) (2 p+1)}\right)$$

This is how far I can go. The infinite series has no known sum, so you just have to take some terms and then run the entire productory (since it's finite) to get some suitable answer. I also checked with W. Mathematica but due to the arbitrariness of $r_k, a, b$ we cannot do much.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
but i have some difficulties in understanding the last integral by using the mean of Hypergeometric functions. could u please help me to understand  this point.

Comment: The last integral is a sort of "special integral" which cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions, and it does not admit a true primitive. By the help of the so called hypergeometric function (google this!) we can obtain a solution by series (which is what hypergeometric functions are indeed). Here the result is not really analytical in the usual sense, but of course there might be special cases with respect upon the parameters of the HGF. For example:

$$_2F_1(a, 1, 1, z) = (1-z)^{-a}$$

Hence a simple special case. In your integral no variable is known hence it has to be left so.

Comment: i tried to solve the  integral by Hypergeometric functions

$F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,Z)=\frac{1}{\beta(\beta,\gamma-\beta)} \int_{0}^{1} t^{\beta-1}(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1} (1-z t)^{-\alpha} dt$
but i couldn't reach the final answer maybe because this integral is defined between 0 and 1. can i use it for the interval [0.5 2].
Mnay Thanx

Comment: $r_k$ could be any gaussian random variable
$a=0.1 b=1.1$
i was trying this step to reach the solution  but still there is somthing missing
could u please guide me to reach the right answer of the integration

Comment: $F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,Z)=\frac{1}{\beta(\beta,\gamma-\beta)} \int_{0}^{1} t^{\beta-1}(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1} (1-z t)^{-\alpha} dt$

$F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,Z)=\frac{ \int_{0}^{1} t^{\beta-1}(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1} (1-z t)^{-\alpha}dt}{ \int_{0}^{1} t^{\beta-1}(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1} dt}$

$\int_{0}^{1} y^{2p}(1-y)^{0} dy ( F(1,2p+1,2p+2,\frac{y}{r_k-a}))=\int_{0}^{1} y^{2p}(1-y)^{0} (1-\frac{y}{r_k-a} t)^{-1}dy$
$\frac{ F(1,2p+1,2p+2,\frac{y}{r_k-a})}{(r_k-a)(2p+1)}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y^{2p}}{(r_k-a-y)}dy$

Comment: is it possible to write this integration

$\int_a^b \prod_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{A}e^{-(r_k - A)^2}$\\

suppose $y = r_k - A$\\

in this form\\

$\prod_{k = 1}^{n} \int_{r_k - b}^{r_k - a} \frac{1}{r_k - y} e^{-y^2}\ dy$

I mean to move the product operator to the outside of the integral??
could you pleas give me the reference that u depend on while doing that?
Many thanks